# Change the value in padas base on another column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like to change the value of a pandas column by checking at the value in another column.
An example data is shown below:

```
datetime.   column1 column2
2021-04-10.   1.       20
2021-04-11.   0.       21
2021-04-12.   0.       19
2021-04-13.   1.       12
```

For column 1: when the value is 0. A condition should check if column 2 value is outside the range of 20-22 and if that is the cast it should reset the value from 0 to 1, otherwise it remains as 0.

For Column1: when the value is 1, no action should be taken and should always return 1.

An expected output is given as:

```
datetime.   column1 column2
2021-04-10.   1.       20
2021-04-11.   0.       21
2021-04-12.   1.       19
2021-04-13.   1.       12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.loc[df['column1'].eq(0),'column1'] = 1-df['column2'].between(20,22).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
     datetime.  column1  column2
0  2021-04-10.      1.0       20
1  2021-04-11.      0.0       21
2  2021-04-12.      1.0       19
3  2021-04-13.      1.0       12
```